# error in do loop SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need my data temp dataset to generate 2 columns.
word1 and word2. Both will have blank values. The value in the do loop will change. 2 is just a dummy number.

Can some one tell me how to interpret this error ?

```
 data temp(drop=k);
 do k=1 to 2;
  word&k=.;
  output;
end;
run;
```

### Logs -

```
 180
```

WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference K not resolved.
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an array, not a macro variable; you're misunderstanding how macro variables work.

```
data temp(drop=k);
  array word[2];
  do k=1 to 2;
    word[k]=.;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Macro variables are an entirely different system, and require a different kind of loop (and, to be inside a macro, the way you're trying to do it).

Comment: hey thanks this helps.. 
Can you please let me know how to write this in a macro program using %do loop ?

Comment: You wouldn't; you'd write it using an array.  If you want to use a %do loop, read a primer on SAS macros, they teach that first thing basically.